# Crazy dialog pop in jQuery Mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, dialog

I need some help with a problem that driving me crazy ...
I'm trying to use a dialog pop, all my pages are inside a single html file. If I use the following code to call the pop dialog:

```
<a href = "# page1" id = "lnk" data-inline = "true" style = "position: absolute; left: 5%; bottom: 5%" data-rel = "dialog" data-transition = "pop "> Click here </ a> </ td>
```

And as I use only a single source for all html pages, I am using a .js to handle the events, etc:

```
/ / Load all events 
document.addEventListener ("deviceready" onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {

   / / Index events is


   / / Events for page1
   $ (document). delegate ('# page1', 'pageInit', function() {
      / / ...
   }

   / / events pages is outher
   $(document).delegate('#page...', 'pageInit', function() {
      / / ...
   }
}
```

The dialog is pop with a vast white space between the header and the body of the page.
This link them in the same html.
I could see that the problem occurs with the following line:

```
document.addEventListener ("deviceready" onDeviceReady, false);
```

One solution I saw was to use external html files only for dialog pop, however when navigating between screens a page containing the information being presented this dialog pop and lock app.

Data for the index script:

```
<!--- STYLE --->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="style/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/jquery.mobile.iscrollview-pull.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/smart_mobile_theme.css" />

<!--- JS --->
<script src="js/cordova-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/iscroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.iscrollview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Page1

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="g">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h4>Title</h4>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
           <div >
                <input id="mail" type="email" data-inline="true" placeholder="Mail" />
                <button id="btnMail" >Send</button> 
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma in your addEventListener call.

Comment: Sorry there is a comma in the original code ... 

`code`document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

This problem only occurs on the android browser works normally. In the console does not display error. By removing the script that is required of the device ready this blank empty space disappears.

Comment: That suggests something going wrong in your pageinit handler, which you have not included. Either that or some CSS that is being applied too broadly. The android webview isn't an exact match to any browser, and there are a lot of small details which don't work quite the same as even the browser on the same device.

Comment: Friend I checked the files and CSS are ok, I have checked every line in index.js (file containing all methods of app), and commenting on each line of the file. Functional js only is the dialog by commenting this line:
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

or commenting on the script line cord in the index.html:
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
Any conflict occurs even with these two files involving the device ready not know what that might be.

Comment: Another problem I'm seeing that this place is that the texts contained in utf-8 in my js accented letters (&aacute;) are not being properly changed at runtime. Also problem is corrected with the above method. Detail: use everything as UTF-8.

Comment: I solved my problem
As I am new to jQuery programming, realize constant research to do my job and solve my problems. And since the internet is a vast source of knowledge and there is several ways to solve problems.
I had seen that could make switching screens in the following ways:

<a href="#screen1"></a>

//or

$(location).attr('href', '#screen1');

/ / Or correct as the jQuery site

$.mobile.changePage('#screen1', 'slide');

Using only as a way of navigating the code form of the jQuery site it's work!

Even had errors in reading the charset of javascript. Now everything is ok.